# Running Promises in array in series

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, promise

I have an array of links, but executing them in parallel like this makes the server hang up and time out

```
var pages = linksArray.then(function(arr){
    return arr.map(function(link) {
              return loader(link);
              });
          }).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            return data;
          });
```

How can I load the pages that are associated with the array of links, in series? loader is a promise that gets the html

Comment: What do you expect (need?) `pages` will be, and what do you expect (need) as `data` in the `.then` block?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have an array of links, and want to get each corresponding page in an array of strings

Comment: @Jaromanda X Friend, how is it supposed tp work, it hasn't returned after 5 minutes

Comment: @Jaromanda X Yes, friend please clarify how it works

Comment: @Jaromanda X So, the reason that it doesn't return, is that some pages loading fails?
  var ret = promise.then(function() {
            return loader(link.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ''));
        });
        pArray.push(ret);
        return ret;
    }, Promise.resolve())
the last part  ", Promise.resolve()", how can there be a comma?

Comment: Sorry for spamming you,  bothering you to much, friend. It doesn't return, and I can't figure out how to modify it...

Comment: You can use Bluebird's `Promise.each()`. It runs them in series automatically. Otherwise, use `Array.reduce()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most common way of running an array of Promises in series is using `array.reduce` - like so

```
var pages = linksArray.then(function (arr) {
    var pArray = [];
    return arr.reduce(function (promise, link) {
        var ret = promise.then(function() {
            return loader(link)
             // the next 3 lines will ensure all links are processed - any failed links will resolve with a value == false
            .catch(function(err) {
                return false;
            });
        });
        pArray.push(ret);
        // next three lines log when each loader has finished
        ret.then(function() {
            console.log('finished', link);
        });
        return ret;
    }, Promise.resolve())
    .then(function() {
        return Promise.all(pArray);
    });
})
```

You can then access the results like this

```
pages.then(function (data) {
    // data is an array of results of loader
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) { // any errors should be logged here
    console.log(err);
});
```

> How it works: simply, each call to `loader` "waits" until the previous call is resolved before being executed - the effective promise for each loader is saved in an array. Once the last loader resolves, the `Promise.all` returns a Promise which resolves to an array of values of each of the calls to `loader`
>
> If you need to know how array.reduce works - read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: My download speed is 0.5Mbps, upload is 6Mbps, number of links are 750,
still not returning after 20 min. Any idea?

Comment: so, with the latest edited code, you are not getting anything? look in developer tools console ... any errors? look in the developer tools network tab ... any indication that the requests are being sent? succeeding? failing?

Comment: 750 links! - maybe rather than limiting to one at a time, you could use [promise-throttle](https://github.com/JMPerez/promise-throttle) - this allows a set number of requests per second

Comment: Just restarted it, with the new code. I am running node from the git bash console. Don't know how I can monitor if anything is sent

Comment: oh, this is node  - surely you can add `console.log`s in appropriate part of the code to see what it's doing

Comment: Ahh, of course, but got a whole Promise pending after adding the console.log
pArray.push(ret);
        console.log(ret);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104044/discussion-between-lasse-karagiannis-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: you're reading 750 links, one after the other, if it takes 200ms for one, it will take 2.5 **minutes** to do 750 - the fact that you give up after 20 minutes suggests it's taking over 1.6 seconds per request

Comment: rather than logging what you seem to be logging, which will always be pending promises, log something **useful** ... see edited code

Comment: It is printing out that it finishes...still printing :)

Comment: I'd consider looking into [promise-throttle](https://github.com/JMPerez/promise-throttle) as mentioned before. depending on the server, you could get better performance

Comment: Yes, that might be the key to better perfomance. Still printing..:)